# Storing pid file for a daemon run as user

Tags: linux, daemon, pid

Is there a preferred place to store a pid file for a daemon that's run as a user? /var/run is the standard place, but this is for a user daemon so it doesn't have write privileges there. Presumably my daemon will be started from .profile or .bashrc or something. Is just saving it to /tmp a bad idea?

Comment: Saving to /tmp is no good since any naming convention you'd invent (eg `/tmp/<username>/<pid>.pid`) could be already used by another app and you won't be able to create the file. Using a random dirname under `/tmp` ruins the idea of pid file - to be able to get the pid quickly without scanning the process list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it's being run for a user, let's see, what sort of storage exists that is user-specific.

Hmmm.

That's it! The home directory. I knew it would come to me eventually :-)

---

Sorry for the light jab. Seriously, I would just stash the PID into `$HOME/.daemon.pid` or `~/.daemon.pid` (how you name the file is up to you of course).

This is, of course, assuming you will only have one daemon running for a user. If not, you'll need to be a bit trickier.

---

And hopefully allaying your fears that a user will inadvertently delete unknown files in their home directory, that's why you make it "hidden" by starting it with a `.` character.

Most non-experienced users should never even *see* these and experienced users should know better than to muck about with them.

Comment: Well the user sees the hom directory, and I think they'd be more likely to delete the file if they see it in ~ not knowing what it was

Comment: @Falmarri: And what is the danger in that? If you really need the PID again, you can always look in the process table. The PID file is just a convenience.

Comment: That's why you put a `.` in front of it. Users who don't know what they're doing will probably never even know that it exists. And if they do regularly see the hidden files, just one mistake deleting `.bashrc` will teach them the error of their ways :-) If you are _really_ paranoid, put the PID into `~/.dont_EVER_delete_me_or_you_WILL_be_sorry/.daemon.pid`.

Comment: This has one major drawback: unlike /var/run, the user home does not get cleared after a reboot.

Comment: @augurar, I would suggest that, if a user is maintaining their own "temporary" file area, it's their responsibility to actually maintain it :-) The FHS states that users *may* be allowed to have subdirectories under `/run` (the "new" `/var/run`) but this must be set up carefully. I often find it's easier to use `~` subdirectories since the permissions there should *already* be okay. In any case, it's easy to create a system boot task to `rm -rf /home/*/run/*` to ensure all users temp areas are cleared out on boot.

Comment: A more extensive answer is here: https://superuser.com/a/1127720/71795 a wrong answer which seems very elegant is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5174433. Summary: use either `/tmp` or `~`.

Answer (score 9):

The [XDG Basedir specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) defines where you should store these.
The variable `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` defines it's location, although it has no default.
The most common fallback (if the variable is unset) is `/tmp/service-$USER.id`.

This helps keep uncluttered homedirs, while keeping all runtime data in

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you go for a subdirectory within the user's home directory.

```
~/.programname/.pid
```

If there is any other user configuration data, you can store that in here too, in order to avoid cluttering up the home directory.