# How to run cron daemon in foreground with non-privileged user?

Tags: linux, cron

I use [Supervisor (supervisord)](http://supervisord.org) to run some service in a CentOS-based Docker container, which additionally has `cronie` installed for triggering some periodic actions on that service.

Supervisor requires the processes that it manages to run in foreground (it daemonizes them itself). That isn't a problem since `crond` has `-n` flag for this. The problem is that it cannot be started as a non-root user, even if you run it in foreground:

`crond: can't open or create /var/run/crond.pid: Permission denied`

Is there any way to solve this issue? Or maybe there are some alternative (simple, lightweight) scheduling solutions that fit the requirements?

Comment: FYI https://stackoverflow.com/a/5174433/1207049

Comment: @marekful That pid file manipulation doesn't help. I already tried, and `crond` fails with an another error then.

Comment: Similar issue is solved here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47668626/3514821

Comment: @sanathmeti No. I'm not about running cron jobs as a specified user. I'm about starting the daemon itself. Read the question again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so
but you can try another point of view & dedicate a useland scheduler within or without its own container to this task

this one will run a scheduler trigger on scripts stored on a shared volume do the containers it has to have access to..

Comment: What's the point? How it solves the problem of running it as non-root user?

Comment: user land scheduler means no-root

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the permission of the cron service to run with its creator user/group that will fix the problem.

This can be done by updating your Docker file with `RUN chmod gu+s /usr/sbin/crond` and rebuilding it.