# Preferred location for PID file of system daemon run as non-root user

Tags: linux, security, locking, daemon, pid

My question is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957242/storing-pid-file-for-a-daemon-run-as-user), but the processes in question are run from cron, and by non-root users.  As such, many of the users don't really have home dirs (or their home dirs point to `/usr/share/package_name` which is not an ideal location for a PID file).

Storing in `/var/run` is problematic, because this directory is not writable except by root.

I could use `/tmp`, but I wonder if this is ideal for security reasons.

I could arrange for a startup script to create a directory in `/var/run` which is owned by the appropriate user (I can't do this at package install time, as `/var` is often mounted as tmpfs, so is not persistent).

What's the best practice here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice question :), I'm having exactly the same at moment. I'm not sure if this is the correct answer but I hope it helps and I would appreciate feedback as well.

I've googled around and found that registering the per user daemon as a dbus service is an elegant solution. dbus could make sure that the service runs just once. no need for a pidfile.

Another solution (my current) would be to create the PID file in a directory like:

```
$HOME/.yourdaemon/pid
```

After your comment I realized, that you cannot write to home. I would suggest to look into dbus

**Update**

I have an idea. What if you are using /tmp, but looking for a pidfile which is called yourdaemon.pid.UNIQUE_KEY and is owned by the daemon's user? This should work fine.

`UNIQUE_KEY` should be random generated (preferred is using tempnam as it is race condition proof).